# Where is "Block New.ens" on my Reaktor 6 on Mac?

Tags: reaktor

I'm beginning my adventure with Reaktor 6. I have mac and I just downloaded the software (demo version). I'm trying to follow some tutorial to generate any sound, and found this one:

However I have no "Block New.ens" in my library. How can I get one? Or is there some tutorial for absolute beginners?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one with this question: https://vi-control.net/community/threads/reaktor-6-query-on-the-correct-blocks-new-ens-file.123629/

Comment: And still not the only one without the answer :/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a basic customer support question, better addressed to the developer.

Comment: Questions like this should not be addressed here at all. It encourages and rewards bad behavior from the software manufacturer. Talk to Native Instruments, they caused this, they're the ones who should be spending their time supporting their demo version.